# Web scraping with beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape links from this page(https://www.setlist.fm/search?query=nightwish)

Whilst this code does retrieve the links i want it also comes back with a load of other stuff i don't want.

Example of what i want:

- setlist/nightwish/2022/quarterback-immobilien-arena-leipzig-germany-2bbca8f2.html
- setlist/nightwish/2022/brose-arena-bamberg-germany-3bf4963.html
- setlist/nightwish/2022/arena-gliwice-gliwice-poland-3bc9dc7.html

Can i use beautiful soup to get these links or do i need to use regex?

```
url = 'https://www.setlist.fm/search?query=nightwish'
reqs = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')

urls = []
for link in soup.select('a'):
    urls.append(link)
    print(link.get('href'))
```

Comment: Can you say what are the unwanted stuff you are getting?

Comment: Sure   None
edit?setlist=73bc8e71&step=song
edit?setlist=73bc8e71&step=artist
edit?setlist=73bc8e71&step=times
edit?setlist=73bc8e71&step=tour
assign-festival?setlist=73bc8e71
report/setlist?setlist=73bc8e71
setlists/nightwish-13d6fd01.html
search?artist=13d6fd01&query=tour:%28Human.+:%7C%7C:+Nature.+World+Tour%29
venue/arena-gliwice-gliwice-poland-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check to see if the code snippet below is useful.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.setlist.fm/search?query=nightwish'

html_content = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")

for g_data in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'link-primary'}, href=True): 
    print(g_data['href'])
```

Comment: Just want to add something to @CoolNetworking's answer. You have tried to collect all the links when you have written `soup.select('a')`. @CoolNetworking has correctly pointed out the class of the css selector from where you need the links from.

Comment: Hi thanks for this but it does not work. I cannot see any class called 'link-primary' , i assume this is why nothing happens.